# trying to scrape youtube using scrapy and get no data

Tags: python, scrapy

so i am learning scrapy and would like to get data from a youtube channel

> https://www.youtube.com/c/JohnWatsonRooney
> for example

so i open up the shell and fetch it
and for example i would like to get the subcriber count
i use response.xpath('//*[@id="subscriber-count"]')
i tried with the css selector and many other things
nothing seems to be working
help !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is entirely dynamic that's why you can't pull the data. You have to use either an automation tool something like selenium or API (Youtube provides API). As you want to grab subscriptions count right now.So I use selenium as an example

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/c/JohnWatsonRooney'
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(3)

subcriber_count=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="subscriber-count"]').text
print(subcriber_count)
```

**Output:**

A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

```
26.5K subscribers
```